# Hiding menuItem for non admin users in Angular 2

Tags: angular, menuitem

How can I hide the Maintanence menuItem for the users that are not admins ?

I have this in my app.menu.ts :

```
import { MenuItem } from '../fw/services/menu.service';

export let initialMenuItems: Array<MenuItem> = [
  {
    text: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'glyphicon-dashboard',
    route: '/authenticated/dashboard',
    submenu: null
  },
  {
    text: 'Books',
    icon: 'glyphicon-book',
    route: null,
    submenu: [{...}]
  },
  {
    text: 'Authors',
    icon: 'glyphicon-user',
    route: null,
    submenu: [{...}],
  },
  {
    text: 'Maintenance',
    icon: 'glyphicon-wrench',
    route: null,
    submenu: [{...}]
  }]
```

My menu.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface MenuItem {
  text: string,
  icon: string,
  route: string,
  submenu: Array<MenuItem>
}

@Injectable()
export class MenuService {

 items: Array<MenuItem>;
 isVertical = false;
 showingLeftSideMenu = false;
 displayMaintainance = false;

 showMaintenance() {
    var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if (currentUser.isAdmin === true) {
       return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
 };

}
```

I managed to make the maintanence links not accesible with an isAdminGuard like this, but I would rather hide the menu completely, it makes more sense.

```
 { path: 'book-detail/:id/:operation', component: BookDetailComponent, canActivate: [IsAdminGuard] }
```

I also have that showMaintanence() function but I don't really manage to use it in app.menu.ts, I think I'm missing something..

What would be the best way to do this ? Thanks !

Comment: How does your HTML code for the navigation look like?

Comment: How do you mean that you don't manage to use the showMaintanence() in app.menu.ts? The easiest way would be to use it there and then decide whether to show or hide the menuitem

Comment: And how should I do this ? I tried creating an extra field and accessing the function there, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an *ngIf around the nav component.

Please do not save important information in the local storage as any user can manipulate those entries using built-in functions in every modern browser. Setting a bit from 0 to 1 is no problem at all!

Comment: It's safer to assume that the whole front-end client is editable by a user pretty much at will and don't worry too much about them messing with low level stuff. Better to secure your API and let the application stop working as a result of them messing around.

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do would be to add an extra field to the menu object, like

```
{
    text: 'Maintenance',
    icon: 'glyphicon-wrench',
    route: null,
    submenu: [{...}],
    admin: true
}
```

Then using a method like

```
public displayItem(userIsAdmin, menuItemIsAdmin) {
    return isAdmin || !menuItemIsAdmin
}
```

Then in the template for the menu in the HTML, during the loop I'd use `[hidden]=displayItem(user.isAdmin, item.admin)`. You'd still want a guard in the logic, but it would hide the UI if `user.isAdmin` was false, and `item.admin` was true, and show it in all other cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay using a library which handles stuff like that, take look in [ngx-permissions](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions). It's super easy to use and solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by adding this into my menu-item component:

```
 @Input() item = <MenuItem>null;
 userAdmin = true;

  ngOnInit() : void {

   var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
   if (currentUser.isAdmin === false && this.item.text === 'Maintenance') {
        this.userAdmin = false;
   }
   ...
  }
```

And *ngIf="userAdmin" in the html. Thanks for the answers !